# .htaccess rewriting rule with added question mark

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Problem is simple, but not understanding of how htaccess works, makes me confused.

Htaccess contains:

```
RewriteRule ^up/(.*).mp4$ upload/vid.php?id=$1.mp4 [NC]
```

Simple as that, once i use:
`mydomain.com/up/movie2.mp4`, 
it will redirect to:
`mydomain.com/upload/vid.php?id=movie2.mp4`

How can i add to my htaccess file so once i put:
`mydomain.com/up/movie2.mp4?dl`
it will redirect to
`mydomain.com/upload/dl.php?id=movie2.mp4`

Any ideas how can i make it works?

Comment: Dunno why but simple:
RewriteRule `^up/(.*).mp4?dl$ upload/dl.php?id=$1.mp4 [NC]`
doesn't work ;(

Comment: Please edit your answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` to match `?dl`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dl [NC]
RewriteRule ^up/(.+\.mp4)$ upload/dl.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^up/(.+\.mp4)$ upload/vid.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I dont really get how 'program' knows how these 2 lines differs:

`RewriteRule ^up/(.+\.mp4)$ upload/dl.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`


`RewriteRule ^up/(.+\.mp4)$ upload/vid.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Is this the order that matters or...?

Comment: Because first rule has an extra `RewriteCond`

Comment: Yes order also matters as `?dl` matching rule must be placed before 2nd rule

Comment: Oh so it really does matter if i write any rule just after `RewriteCond`, means i can put `RewriteCond` before every rule if i want to change it. Now i understand ;)) Thanks @anubhava